# Posted Image size is changing while using facebook graph api

Tags: android

I posted message and image to facebook wall using graph api.Here is the code I used

```
if(i==1){   


        String res=  UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&source="+imageUrl);
            Log.e("post response",res);
            if(res.contains("id")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Both the message and image are posted successfully,but the image size is taking as thumbnail.I used both "source" and "picture" parameters,but the result is same.

I am getting these images from my local database.
I checked the image size of that Url,it is 240*320 size,but it is displaying in small size in my facebook.

Comment: Images posted to facebook wall using graph api are displaying in fixed size?     String res=  UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&source="+imageUrl);

Answer (score 0):

Posting to the wall using graph api will always result in the image size chosen by facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

This is to maintain uniformity in the feed. You can post as big an image as you want but it will be resized while being displayed in the feed. The user can view a bigger version when he clicks on it though.

Image sizes can be set while querying them from facebook. See:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Comment: While posting to facebook normally by using facebook site,image is shown in big size.But when I use graph api (/me/feed?picture=imageurl),the image is displayed in default size.And I cant able to click and maximize this.

Comment: I tried to post 240*320px image,but it is displaying in very small size in facebook